# How to check if character is UTF-16

Tags: java, validation, utf-16

I would like to validate outgoing Strings. The rule is that they have to be UTF-16 and below.

How can you check if character is a valid UTF-16 char? Can I do it by some Java method or by regex?

Thanks for info

Comment: What do you mean by "and below"?  UTF-8?

Comment: Every character in Java is UTF-16. Therefore this is no real question.

Comment: @UwePlonus that's not really true, you can have invalid character sequences in a Java string.  Just because each character is 16 bits doesn't mean that it's UTF-16.

Comment: @LaceCard which characters are invalid in Java? Java uses UTF-16 internally and some characters are part of a two-character sequence. So for them alone they are invalid but they are still UTF-16 characters that are part of another Unicode character.

Comment: @UwePlonus: every `char` value is a valid UTF-16 *code unit*. *Not all of them* are valid codepoints! (specifically those referring to low or high surrogates). And "UTF-16 character" is ... not really a specified thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any `char` in Java is always a valid UTF-16. But a sequence of chars may be invalid, that is in surrogate pairs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) higher surrogate char must be followed by lower surrogate char. If this is what you mean then you can try this function

```
static boolean isValidSequence(char[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isHighSurrogate(a[i])) {
            if (i < a.length - 1 && Character.isLowSurrogate(a[i + 1])) {
                i++;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (Character.isLowSurrogate(a[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can also take a look at this func http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ReturnscodetrueifthespecifiedcharactersequenceisavalidsequenceofUTF16charvalues.htm

Comment: You can also use `Charset.forName("UTF-16").newDecoder().canDecode(CharBuffer.wrap(theArray))`

Comment: Not to mention 'non-characters'.

Comment: @fge There is no method `canDecode()...`